# Solving an equation involving the sum of square roots of a quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

So I am building a computer program.

In the program I need to build a function that takes this arguments {a, b, c, d, e, f, s, u}, and returns back the value of x in this equation:

$$
\sqrt{\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(\left(u\left(x-e\right)+f\right)-b\right)^2}+\sqrt{\left(x-c\right)^2+\left(\left(u\left(x-e\right)+f\right)-d\right)^2}=s
$$

So basically I just need to simplify and solve the equation to get this form: $$ x=\mathrm{everythingElse}$$
And then I can code it.

The problem is that I cant solve this equation, first of all I trying to do it by hand and there is to many arguments I just couldn't solve it, than I tried to use wolfram alpha but it failed as well due to "execution time exceeded".

Comment: Why not solve numerically? Analytical solution will give you cubic equation and writing a program to solve these is a challenge in its own.

Comment: So, given a line $\ell$ with slope $u$ containing $(e,f)$, you are trying to find the $x$ coordinates point(s) on $\ell$ that intersects a specific ellipse with foci $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. Note that you need $s\geq \sqrt{(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2}$, and even then it is quite possible there is no solution.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you don't have $s$ in your geometric interpretation.

Comment: Ah, $s$ is the major axis of the ellipse. @Abstraction (Was trying to remember the name, so left that out of my description.)

Comment: @Abstraction. I think that the problem reduces to a quadratic. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, just checked it, $x^3$ also goes away. It's rather simple, then.

Comment: @Abstraction. I was typing almost the same when your comment appeared. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$A = u^2+1 \\
B = -2a+2u(f-b-ue) \\
C = a^2+(f-b-ue)^2 \\
D = -2c+2u(f-d-ue) \\
E = c^2+(f-d-ue)^2$$
Now, equation is $\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C}+\sqrt{Ax^2+Dx+E}=s$. After squaring twice, we get:
$$[(B-D)^2-4As^2]x^2-2[BE-BC+Bs^2+CD-DE+Ds^2]x+[C^2-2CE+E^2-2Cs^2-2Es^2+s^4]=0$$
This is quadratic (or maybe linear) equation which can be solved easily. Note that due to squaring we could get extra solutions. Simplest way to remove them is to put found $x$ into initial equality and check if it holds.

Comment: Yep this is it, GREAT answer. Note - I know that eveytime no matter what arguments we put it should give me 2 results for x, so I dont really have to check cause we are getting only 2 results. (And when I say no matter what arguments I mean how the program uses this function)

Comment: If it is linear, then that is only because the ellipsis is degenerate - that is, just the line segment between the two foci $(a,b),(c,d)$.

Comment: @NoChance It is Currect, Just tested it and got great results.

Answer (score 4):

The equation has the form

$$\sqrt{P(x)}+\sqrt{Q(x)}=s$$ where $P, Q$ are two quadratic polynomials in $x$. [As the coefficients of $x^2$ are the same under both radicals, you can normalize them to be $1$, dividing both members by $\sqrt{u^2+1}$.]

Squaring,

$$P(x)+Q(x)+2\sqrt{P(x)\cdot Q(x)}=s^2,$$
then squaring again

$$4P(x)\cdot Q(x)=(s^2-P(x)-Q(x))^2=s^4-2s^2(P(x)+Q(x))+(P(x)+Q(x))^2$$

or

$$0=s^4-2s^2(P(x)+Q(x))+(P(x)-Q(x))^2.$$

As $P-Q$ simplifies to the first degree, the last expression is quadratic.

Comment: Since $P(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C, Q(x)=Ax^2+Dx+E$, we have $((B-D)^2-4As^2)x^2$-$2(BE-BC+CD-DE+Bs^2+Ds^2)x$+$(C^2-2CE+E^2-2Cs^2-2Es^2+s^4)=0$.

Comment: @Abstraction Wow this is beautiful I will try to do it now.

Comment: @Abstraction: quite right, makes it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that this equation is linear precisely when $s$ is at most the distance between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, and hence we are talking about a degenerate ellipsis (the line segment between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ or an "empty" ellipsis, with no points.

Write $(x,y)=(e,f)+t(1,u)$. Then you want $(x,y)$ to be on the ellipse with foci $(a,b), (c,d)$ and major axis $s$.

Writing $\mathbf u=(a,b)-(e,f), \mathbf  v=(c,d)-(e,f)$, and $\mathbf x = (x,y)-(e,f)=t\mathbf m$, where $\mathbf m=(1,u)$ we are seeing a solution to:

$$|\mathbf u-t\mathbf m|+|\mathbf v-t\mathbf m|=s$$

Squaring, re-arranging, and squaring again gives us:

$$\begin{align}
0&=\left(s^2-|\mathbf u-t\mathbf m|^2-|\mathbf v-t\mathbf m|^2\right)^2- 4|\mathbf u-t\mathbf m|^2|\mathbf v-t\mathbf m|^2\\
&=s^4-2s^2\left(|\mathbf u-t\mathbf m|^2+|\mathbf v-t\mathbf m|^2\right)+\left(|\mathbf u-t\mathbf m|^2-|\mathbf v-t\mathbf m|^2\right)^2\\
&=s^4-2s^2\left(|\mathbf u|^2+|\mathbf v|^2 -2t(\mathbf u + \mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf  m+2t^2|\mathbf  m|^2\right)+\left(|\mathbf u|^2-|\mathbf v|^2+2t(\mathbf u-\mathbf v)\cdot\mathbf  m)\right)^2
\end{align}$$

So this equation is linear in $t$ precisely when $$\left|(\mathbf u-\mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf m\right|=s|\mathbf m|$$

But:

$$1\geq |\cos \theta |= \frac{|(\mathbf u-\mathbf v)\cdot \mathbf m|}{|\mathbf u-\mathbf v||\mathbf m|}=\frac{s}{|\mathbf u-\mathbf v|}$$

If $s> |\mathbf u-\mathbf v|$, we reach a contradiction.

(You can deal with the case $\mathbf u=\mathbf v$ separately.)